Geometric interpretation of $h^0\mathcal{I}_C(n)$

Let $C$ be a projective curve and $\mathcal{I}_C$ its ideal sheaf defined as the kernel of  $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_C$.
I have read in a lot of books that $h^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{I}_C(n))$ is the number of independent surfaces of degree $n$ that contain $C$. However, I have never seen a proof (maybe I missed it) and I can't find one myself.
I think that it could be easier to think of $C$ as a Riemann surface (so maybe in a special case) and to interpret $\mathcal{O}_C$ and $\mathcal{I}_C$ in this situation but it doesn't really help me very much.
Could you help me with this ? Or maybe could you give me a reference where I could find a proof ? (I have already searched in the books of Hartshorne and Vakil, without finding anything).

simply because it is the kernel of the restriction $ H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m)) \rightarrow H^0(C, \mathcal{O}_C(m)) $

I knew that but I still don't see how to get the result. Where do we see the surfaces and their degree ?

$H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(m))$ consists of homogenous degree $m$ polynomials i.e. degree $m$ hypersurfaces. The map is evaluating this homogenous polynomial on $C$, and saying $F$ lies in the kernel precisely means $C$ lies in the locus $F=0$
